# Get HTTP Command in client and MEMO

Tags: c++, windows, delphi, builder

Hello

I want use "Get" command such as:

`Get https://api.demo.website.com/api/2/public/something`

This is a public info and does not need authentication.

When I use the URL in a browser, I receive proper respond, also in another software of mine, I copy paste this code below, always showing me bland result in memo.

Maybe I will start from scratch to avoid the bug, but can anyone tell me if there is something wrong i this code?

```
TMemoryStream *Response=new TMemoryStream;
TNameValueArray nva;
NetHTTPRequest1->URL=URLEdit->Text;
NetHTTPRequest1->Get(URLEdit->Text, Response, nva);
Memo1->Lines->LoadFromStream(Response);
```

Answer (score 2):

When `Get()` is finished writing to the MemoryStream, the stream's `Position` is left at the *end* of the stream, so there is no data available for the Memo to load. You need to reset the `Position` back to the *beginning* before loading the stream into the Memo:

```cpp
NetHTTPRequest1->Get(URLEdit->Text, Response, nva);
Response->Position = 0; // <-- ADD THIS
Memo1->Lines->LoadFromStream(Response);
```